# How to read tickers from CSV and loop through them

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I am trying to store my tickers in a CSV file, having my codes read from the CSV and run through some codes,My CSV has only 3 lines:

Ticker

YHOO

IBM

below is my code.

```
Stocks <- read.csv(file.choose(),head=T) # tried to put in sep="," no luck
#loop through the tickers
for (i in Stocks){

getSymbols(i) 
# do something here
}
```

then i get this error 
Error in do.call(paste("getSymbols.", symbol.source, sep = ""), list(Symbols = current.symbols,  : 
  could not find function "getSymbols.1"

I try to debug, so i do

> for (i in Stocks) {print (i)}

[1] YHOO IBM

Levels: IBM YHOO

this is what i get. i think when i am trying to run the loop the code is taking YHOO IBM as 1 ticker rather than loading 1 ticker at a time.
Can someone advise what is the proper way of reading from a CSV file and loop through the ticker?
appreciate the advise!

Comment: there's a _really good chance_ your line breaks are problematic and we can't diagnose that with hand-typed "data"

Comment: Can you create the CSV file within the R code to make this reproducible?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your read statement nor your data.frame. The only problem is your `for` loop.   You need:

```
 for (i in Stocks$Ticker) {print (i)}
[1] "YHOO"
[1] "IBM"
```

Answer (score 0):

getSymbols can take a vector as an input so there is no need for a loop, for example you could do something like:

```
Stocks <- read.csv(file.choose(),head=T)     

getSymbols(as.vector(Stocks$Ticker))
```

Comment: just adding: `getSymbols` in `quantmod` library